# Remove an '\\n\\t\\t\\t'-element from list

Tags: python, regex

I got the following list called "phonenumbers". I struggle to remove the elements which contain '\n\t\t\t' and '\n\t\t\t\t'.
I tried "try and except"-methode and remove('\n\t\t\t\t') but couldnt make it work.
Any tips?

> ['(02271) 6 79', ' 70', '\n\t\t\t', '(02271) 6 79', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 70', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02181) 27 0', '\n\t\t\t\t', '3-0', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02181) 27 0', '\n\t\t\t\t', '3-0', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02161) 24 19', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 40', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02161) 24 19', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 40', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02131) 66 67', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 10', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02131) 66 67', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 10', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02103) 39 00', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 93', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02103) 39 00', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 93', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02173) 2 04 7', '\n\t\t\t\t', '3-0', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02173) 2 04 7', '\n\t\t\t\t', '3-0', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02235) 9 23 04', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 30', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02235) 9 23 04', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 30', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\t', '(0221) 3 46 79 40', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\t', '(0221) 3 46 79 40', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02232) 4 23', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 05', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02232) 4 23', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 05', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(0157) 86 85 74', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 43', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(0157) 86 85 74', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 43', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02181) 2 78 11', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 47', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02181) 2 78 11', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 47', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02181) 47 49 0', '\n\t\t\t\t', '0-0', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02181) 47 49 0', '\n\t\t\t\t', '0-0', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02202) 1 88', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 60', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02202) 1 88', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 60', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(0211) 23 80', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 70', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(0211) 23 80', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 70', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02235) 9 23 0', '\n\t\t\t\t', '4-0', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02235) 9 23 0', '\n\t\t\t\t', '4-0', '\n\t\t\t']

Comment: Post what you have tried, and someone might help you fix it.

Comment: Perhaps instead of removing the items, you should modify the code that generates the list to not insert them in the first place. How is this list being generated?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley its done by rendering the page with Qt first and then use lxml to extract the list via tree.xpath: phonenumbers = tree.xpath('//span[@class="text nummer_ganz"]//text()') -- website is: https://www.gelbeseiten.de/schluesselfertigbau/bergheim,,,,,umkreis-50000/s1

Comment: `str.strip()` will remove all of `'\n\t\t\t\t'` so you can do `[e for e in ur_lst if e.strip()]` to filter out the elements that are all whitespace. No regex needed.

Comment: @dawg: Very good point, though I'd even use `lst = [number for item in lst for number in [item.strip()] if number]` to have the items stripped in the resulting list. Have updated my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You could go for a simple expression like

```
^\s+$
```

In `Python`:

```
import re

lst = ['(02271) 6 79', ' 70', '\n\t\t\t', '(02271) 6 79', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 70', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02181) 27 0', '\n\t\t\t\t', '3-0', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02181) 27 0', '\n\t\t\t\t', '3-0', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02161) 24 19', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 40', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02161) 24 19', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 40', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02131) 66 67', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 10', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02131) 66 67', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 10', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02103) 39 00', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 93', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02103) 39 00', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 93', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02173) 2 04 7', '\n\t\t\t\t', '3-0', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02173) 2 04 7', '\n\t\t\t\t', '3-0', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02235) 9 23 04', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 30', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02235) 9 23 04', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 30', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\t', '(0221) 3 46 79 40', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t\t', '(0221) 3 46 79 40', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02232) 4 23', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 05', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02232) 4 23', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 05', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(0157) 86 85 74', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 43', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(0157) 86 85 74', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 43', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02181) 2 78 11', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 47', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02181) 2 78 11', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 47', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02181) 47 49 0', '\n\t\t\t\t', '0-0', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02181) 47 49 0', '\n\t\t\t\t', '0-0', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02202) 1 88', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 60', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02202) 1 88', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 60', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(0211) 23 80', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 70', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(0211) 23 80', '\n\t\t\t\t', ' 70', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02235) 9 23 0', '\n\t\t\t\t', '4-0', '\n\t\t\t', '\n\t\t\t', '(02235) 9 23 0', '\n\t\t\t\t', '4-0', '\n\t\t\t']

rx = re.compile(r'^\s+$')

lst = [item.strip() for item in lst if not rx.match(item)]
print(lst)
```

This yields and strips all numbers that are not only whitespaces from start to end:

```
['(02271) 6 79', '70', '(02271) 6 79', '70', '(02181) 27 0', '3-0', '(02181) 27 0', '3-0', '(02161) 24 19', '40', '(02161) 24 19', '40', '(02131) 66 67', '10', '(02131) 66 67', '10', '(02103) 39 00', '93', '(02103) 39 00', '93', '(02173) 2 04 7', '3-0', '(02173) 2 04 7', '3-0', '(02235) 9 23 04', '30', '(02235) 9 23 04', '30', '(0221) 3 46 79 40', '(0221) 3 46 79 40', '(02232) 4 23', '05', '(02232) 4 23', '05', '(0157) 86 85 74', '43', '(0157) 86 85 74', '43', '(02181) 2 78 11', '47', '(02181) 2 78 11', '47', '(02181) 47 49 0', '0-0', '(02181) 47 49 0', '0-0', '(02202) 1 88', '60', '(02202) 1 88', '60', '(0211) 23 80', '70', '(0211) 23 80', '70', '(02235) 9 23 0', '4-0', '(02235) 9 23 0', '4-0']
```

---

As @dawg points out, a regular expression is not really needed, actually:

```
lst = [number for item in lst for number in [item.strip()] if number]
```

Comment: Thanks for all your answers guys. I tried them all, but none worked for me. Probably my list isnt a "real" list? @Jan when i use the list "lst" which u defined, it works. But when i write lst = phonenumbers it doesnt... my list is created by rendering the page with Qt first and then use lxml to extract the list via tree.xpath: phonenumbers = tree.xpath('//span[@class="text nummer_ganz"]//text()') -- website is: gelbeseiten.de/schluesselfertigbau/bergheim,,,,,umkreis-5000‌​0/s1

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
result = [i for i in lst if not i.endswith('\t\t')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `list-comprehension` to create a list of `strings` where each one has to past the test that `all` of the characters (`c`) in the `string` are `in`: `'\t\n'`. I think that this is the most efficient, general purpose solution that will work for `strings` that only contain `tabs` and `newlines`, it is also extremely readable in Python:

```
[i for i in lst if all(c not in '\t\n' for c in i)]
```

which gives the correct result of:

```
['(02271) 6 79', ' 70', '(02271) 6 79', ' 70', '(02181) 27 0', '3-0', '(02181) 27 0', '3-0', '(02161) 24 19', ' 40', '(02161) 24 19', ' 40', '(02131) 66 67', ' 10', '(02131) 66 67', ' 10', '(02103) 39 00', ' 93', '(02103) 39 00', ' 93', '(02173) 2 04 7', '3-0', '(02173) 2 04 7', '3-0', '(02235) 9 23 04', ' 30', '(02235) 9 23 04', ' 30', '(0221) 3 46 79 40', '(0221) 3 46 79 40', '(02232) 4 23', ' 05', '(02232) 4 23', ' 05', '(0157) 86 85 74', ' 43', '(0157) 86 85 74', ' 43', '(02181) 2 78 11', ' 47', '(02181) 2 78 11', ' 47', '(02181) 47 49 0', '0-0', '(02181) 47 49 0', '0-0', '(02202) 1 88', ' 60', '(02202) 1 88', ' 60', '(0211) 23 80', ' 70', '(0211) 23 80', ' 70', '(02235) 9 23 0', '4-0', '(02235) 9 23 0', '4-0']
```

---

You could also use [**`str.isspace()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace) which is shorter but would probably (I'm not `100%` sure) be *slightly* slower as it checks *all* `whitespace` characters:

```
[i for i in lst if not i.isspace()]
```

which gives the same result.