# Python & Scrapy output: "\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

I'M learning scraping with Scrapy and having some issues with some code giving me a weird output that I don't understand. Can someone explain to me why I am getting a bunch "\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t"

I found this solution on Stack overflow:
[Remove an '\\n\\t\\t\\t'-element from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47953523/remove-an-n-t-t-t-element-from-list)

But I want to learn what is causing it.

Here is my code that is causing my issue. The Strip method from the link above solves it, but as mentioned, I don't understand where it is coming from.

```
import scrapy
import logging
import re

class CitySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'city'
    allowed_domains = ['www.a-tembo.nl']
    start_urls = ['https://www.a-tembo.nl/themas/category/city/']

    def parse(self, response):
        titles = response.xpath("//div[@class='hikashop_category_image']/a")
        
        for title in titles:
            series = title.xpath(".//@title").get()
            link = title.xpath(".//@href").get()

            #absolute_url = f"https://www.a-tembo.nl{link}"
            #absolute_url = response.urljoin(link)

            yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_title)

    def parse_title(self, response):
        rows = response.xpath("//table[@class='hikashop_products_table adminlist table']/tbody/tr")

        for row in rows:
            product_code = row.xpath(".//span[@class='hikashop_product_code']/text()").get()
            product_name = row.xpath(".//span[@class='hikashop_product_name']/a/text()").get()

            yield{
                "Product_code": product_code,
                "Product_name": product_name
                       
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Characters like `\n` are called escape characters.
For example:
`\n` indicates a new line and `\t` signifies a tab. Websites are full of them, although you never see them without inspecting the page. If you want to learn more about escape characters in Python you can read about them [here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html). I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. I didn't really realize that it was from the website, as I had no indication that that was in there.